# Trying to change my font from my assets folder but i am getting error saying "The method setTypeface(Typeface) is undefined for the type Object"

Tags: android, eclipse, typeface

This is my adapter file which i am getting error on eclipse. please help me out guys :) Here is the code you can check it out thank you guys.This is my adapter file which i am getting error on eclipse. please help me out guys :) Here is the code you can check it out thank you guys.

```
private Activity activity;
private List<Pojo> itemsfavorite;
private Pojo objFavoriteBean;
private int row;


public Favorite_Activity_Adapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Pojo> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    this.itemsfavorite = arrayList;


}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((itemsfavorite == null) || ((position + 1) > itemsfavorite.size()))
        return view;

    objFavoriteBean = itemsfavorite.get(position);



    holder.txt_favoquote=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_dis);
    holder.txt_favotitle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);

//you can make any language quotes app just put ttf file in asset->font and below set ttf file

    String fontPathtitle = "font/Kremlin.ttf";
    Typeface tftitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), fontPathtitle);
    holder.txt_categorylistquote).setTypeface(tftitle);
    holder.txt_title).setTypeface(tftitle);

    String formattedString=android.text.Html.fromHtml(objFavoriteBean.getPQuote().toString()).toString();
    holder.txt_favoquote.setText(formattedString);
    return view;

}

public class ViewHolder {


    public Object txt_title;
    public Object txt_categorylistquote;
    public  TextView txt_favoquote,txt_favotitle;

}
```

}

thank you guys

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: “The method setTypeface(Typeface) is undefined for the type Object”

Answer (score 0):

```
String fontPathtitle = "font/Kremlin.ttf";
Typeface tftitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), fontPathtitle);
holder.txt_categorylistquote).setTypeface(tftitle);
holder.txt_title).setTypeface(tftitle);
```

Are you sure thats ok? I see a type error (extra ")" ) in:

```
 holder.txt_categorylistquote).setTypeface(tftitle);
 holder.txt_title).setTypeface(tftitle);
```

should be:

```
 holder.txt_categorylistquote.setTypeface(tftitle);
 holder.txt_title.setTypeface(tftitle);
```

And more important `txt_title` and `txt_categorylistquote` should be TextView(s) inside the ViewHolder, because the `setTypeface()` method is applicable for Textviews

Read more in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface))

Comment: please see the **should be** part in my comment. You have an extra ')' before .setTypeface, which causes a syntax error and the TextView are not recognized by the compiler